# How to transfer values from a list box to a combo box in VB 6.0

Tags: listview, combobox, vb6

So i have 2 listview in my form wherein if i chose a listitems from listview1 and click a command button, it will transfer the selected item to listview2, now i want the items on listview2 to populate my combo box when i click another command button.can you please give me a suggestion on how i can do this? thank you.

here is my current code that populates the combobox of the first item on my listview2.

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ListView2.ListItems.Count
Next i
Combo1.AddItem (ListView2.SelectedItem)

End Sub
```

any idea how i can loop this to show all the items on listview2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add all of the items in list 2 to the combo.  Nothing to do with a selected item at that point.

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
  Dim i As Integer

  Combo1.Clear
  For i = 1 To ListView2.ListItems.Count
    Combo1.AddItem (ListView2.ListItems(i).Text))
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you mean {Combo1.Clear} rather than {ListView2.ListItems.Clear}  and it should be

Comment: @JohnEason - Yes, you are of course correct.  Thank you for noticing that.  I've corrected the code sample.

Comment: sorry guys another related  question, how can i make each item of that combo box to pass in a label 1 by 1? i want to insert that to a loop :) thank you :)

Comment: @JannelynMorales - Sorry, I'm not understanding your additional question.  When you have a new question, please don't use a comment or change this post - create a new question, describing your problem, example code and data, etc.